# Find the total amount of multiple products of the same type - Commerce

Tags: commerce, rules

I've created a rule that sends a thank you email to anyone who donates less-than-or-equal-to a certain amount (which works perfectly), but I cannot figure out how to pull out the total $ amount of all donations on the order and include it in the email.

If it were guaranteed there would only ever be a single donation line item the issue would be simple.  However, there is no guarantee there won't be more than one on a single order, and there will usually be at least one other line item of a different product type included in the order.  I've searched, but cannot figure out how to, for example, calculate the total donation amount for an order that has 2 donation line items of $10 & $20, plus one or more other line items of a different product type, then put the donation total into the thank you email that gets sent out.

Any / all help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Use [commerce_donate](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_donate) module to get donation then this field use in your rules

1. Create a rule add events in Rule
2. Add condition entity has a field (your donation field)
3. Add variables in this you can use php field to get total amount of donation.
4. Add action in email section use token of variables

I am not already try this but hopefully this may work.